# Can I use a property name inside the same property's `setter`?

Tags: python

Assuming the code below:

```
class my_class():
    ''' some code '''
    @property
    def x(self):
        ''' some initialization code '''

    @property.setter
    def x(self, val):
        x = val
```

The above code works on my implementation (3.4.2 on Windows) but is it a safe way to do this or will it be better if I duplicated the initialization code from getter in the setter?

Comment: It "works" by doing nothing.  `x = val` just creates a local variable called `x`.  If you try to do `self.x = val`, you will create an infinite loop.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 1):

As BrenBarn mentioned, the setter doesn't do what you think it does. Here's how to do this right:

```
class my_class(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x # Or whatever name you want except x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        """
        Do whatever you want in here (presumably you want to do *something*
        otherwise why use the property decorator)?
        """
        self._x = value
```